# My verilog VGA driver causes the screen to flicker (Basys2)

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, xilinx, vga

I'm trying to recreate Adventure(1979) in Verilog and so far I have character movement, collision and map generation done. It didn't flicker that much before I separated the maps into modules now it flickers constantly. When I was looking up this issue, I found out that the clock on the Basys2 board is pretty noisy and could be the culprit. However, putting the maps into modules shouldn't have made it worse unless I messed something up. Any idea what happened?

Here's my map generator:

```
module map_generator(clk_vga, reset, CurrentX, CurrentY, HBlank, VBlank, playerPosX, playerPosY, mapData
);

  input clk_vga;
  input reset;
  input [9:0]CurrentX;
  input [8:0]CurrentY;
  input HBlank;
  input VBlank;
  input [9:0]playerPosX;
  input [8:0]playerPosY;

  output [7:0]mapData;

  reg [7:0]mColor;
  reg [5:0]currentMap = 0;

  wire [7:0]startCastle;

  StartCastle StartCastle(
    .clk_vga(clk_vga),
    .CurrentX(CurrentX),
    .CurrentY(CurrentY),
    .mapData(startCastle)
  );

  always @(posedge clk_vga) begin
    if(reset)begin
      currentMap <= 0;
    end
  end

  always @(posedge clk_vga) begin
    if(HBlank || VBlank) begin
      mColor <= 0;
    end
    else begin
      if(currentMap == 4'b0000) begin
        mColor[7:0] <= startCastle[7:0];
      end
      //Add more maps later
    end
  end

  assign mapData[7:0] = mColor[7:0];

endmodule
```

Here's the startCastle:

```
module StartCastle(clk_vga, CurrentX, CurrentY, active, mapData);

  input clk_vga;
  input [9:0]CurrentX;
  input [8:0]CurrentY;
  input active;

  output [7:0]mapData;

  reg [7:0]mColor;

  always @(posedge clk_vga) begin

    if(CurrentY < 40) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end
    else if(CurrentX < 40) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end
    else if(~(CurrentX < 600)) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end
    else if((~(CurrentY < 440) && (CurrentX < 260)) || (~(CurrentY < 440) && ~(CurrentX < 380))) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end else
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b00011100;       
  end

  assign mapData = mColor;
endmodule
```

Here's the VGA driver which is connected to my top module:

```
module vga_driver(clk_50MHz, vs_vga, hs_vga, RED, GREEN, BLUE, HBLANK, VBLANK, CURX, CURY, COLOR, CLK_DATA, RESET);

  input clk_50MHz;
  output vs_vga;
  output hs_vga;
  output [2:0] RED;
  output [2:0] GREEN;
  output [1:0] BLUE;
  output HBLANK;
  output VBLANK;

  reg VS = 0;
  reg HS = 0;

  input RESET;

  //current client data
  input [7:0] COLOR;
  output CLK_DATA;
  output [9:0] CURX;
  output [8:0] CURY;

  //##### Module constants (http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz)
  parameter HDisplayArea = 640;  // horizontal display area
  parameter HLimit = 800;        // maximum horizontal amount (limit)
  parameter HFrontPorch = 16;    // h. front porch
  parameter HBackPorch = 48;         // h. back porch
  parameter HSyncWidth = 96;         // h. pulse width

  parameter VDisplayArea = 480;  // vertical display area
  parameter VLimit = 525;        // maximum vertical amount (limit)
  parameter VFrontPorch = 10;    // v. front porch
  parameter VBackPorch = 33;         // v. back porch
  parameter VSyncWidth = 2;      // v. pulse width 

  //##### Local variables
  wire clk_25MHz;

  reg [9:0] CurHPos = 0; //maximum of HLimit (2^10 - 1 = 1023)
  reg [9:0] CurVPos = 0; //maximum of VLimit
  reg HBlank_reg, VBlank_reg, Blank = 0;

  reg [9:0] CurrentX = 0;    //maximum of HDisplayArea
  reg [8:0] CurrentY = 0;    //maximum of VDisplayArea (2^9 - 1 = 511)

  //##### Submodule declaration
  clock_divider clk_div(.clk_in(clk_50MHz), .clk_out(clk_25MHz));

  //shifts the clock by half a period (negates it)
  //see timing diagrams for a better understanding of the reason for this
  clock_shift clk_shift(.clk_in(clk_25MHz), .clk_out(CLK_DATA));

  //simulate the vertical and horizontal positions
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz) begin
    if(CurHPos < HLimit-1) begin
      CurHPos <= CurHPos + 1;
    end
    else begin
      CurHPos <= 0;

      if(CurVPos < VLimit-1)
        CurVPos <= CurVPos + 1;
      else
        CurVPos <= 0;
    end
    if(RESET) begin
      CurHPos <= 0;
      CurVPos <= 0;
    end
  end

  //##### VGA Logic (http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/640x480@60Hz)

  //HSync logic
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz)
    if((CurHPos < HSyncWidth) && ~RESET)
      HS <= 1;
    else
      HS <= 0;

  //VSync logic     
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz)
    if((CurVPos < VSyncWidth) && ~RESET)
      VS <= 1;
    else
      VS <= 0;

//Horizontal logic      
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz) 
    if((CurHPos >= HSyncWidth + HFrontPorch) && (CurHPos < HSyncWidth + HFrontPorch + HDisplayArea) || RESET)
      HBlank_reg <= 0;
    else
      HBlank_reg <= 1;

  //Vertical logic
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz)
    if((CurVPos >= VSyncWidth + VFrontPorch) && (CurVPos < VSyncWidth + VFrontPorch + VDisplayArea) || RESET)
      VBlank_reg <= 0;
    else
      VBlank_reg <= 1;

  //Do not output any color information when we are in the vertical
  //or horizontal blanking areas. Set a boolean to keep track of this.
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz)
    if((HBlank_reg || VBlank_reg) && ~RESET)
      Blank <= 1;
    else
      Blank <= 0;

  //Keep track of the current "real" X position. This is the actual current X
  //pixel location abstracted away from all the timing details
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz)
    if(HBlank_reg && ~RESET)
      CurrentX <= 0;
    else
      CurrentX <= CurHPos - HSyncWidth - HFrontPorch;

  //Keep track of the current "real" Y position. This is the actual current Y
  //pixel location abstracted away from all the timing details
  always @(posedge clk_25MHz) 
    if(VBlank_reg && ~RESET)
      CurrentY <= 0;
    else
      CurrentY <= CurVPos - VSyncWidth - VFrontPorch;

  assign CURX = CurrentX;
  assign CURY = CurrentY;
  assign VBLANK = VBlank_reg;
  assign HBLANK = HBlank_reg;
  assign hs_vga = HS;
  assign vs_vga = VS;

  //Respects VGA Blanking areas
  assign RED = (Blank) ? 3'b000 : COLOR[7:5];
  assign GREEN = (Blank) ? 3'b000 : COLOR[4:2];
  assign BLUE = (Blank) ? 2'b00 : COLOR[1:0];
endmodule
```

clk_div:

```
module clock_divider(clk_in, clk_out);
  input clk_in;
  output clk_out;

  reg clk_out = 0;

  always @(posedge clk_in)
    clk_out <= ~clk_out;

endmodule
```

clk_shift:

```
module clock_shift(clk_in, clk_out);
  input clk_in;
  output clk_out;

  assign clk_out = ~clk_in;
endmodule
```

Comment: What is your clk_div module? Is it a DCM/PLL?

Comment: I'm using a Spartan 3E which doesn't support PLL, unfortunately. I added the clk_shift and clk_div modules to the OP.

Comment: It may be your problem. Clock generated from logic are **not** analyzed by the timing engine, thus *may* fail timings without reporting it. There is no reason to use a divided clock that way. Instead, generate a `clock_en` signal (half rate of clk) and use it as a clock enable on your 50MHz logic wherever you used `clk_25MHz`. Please try this and tell us if it fixes your issue. Watchout for the timings results, they may fail after this change, since the path will actually be analyzed.

Comment: The Spartan 3E supports DCM, which can be used to generate a divided version of the master clock, as well as an inverted version of it.

Comment: @Jonathan Drolet: at least in Xilinx, clocks generated as outputs from a flip-flop can be routed to BUFG nets and be used as clocks. The synthesizer detects it and treat these signals as clocks.

Comment: I've just tested this design in a Basys module (Spartan 3E-100) and I don't see any flickering. How are you connecting these modules in the top module?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix They can be routed to bufg, but they are not analyzed for period or clock domain crossing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer because I cannot put a photo in a comment.

Is this what your design looks like?
[image: VGA output from the OP design]

My only guess ATM is that you might have misplaced some ports during instantiation of `vga_driver` and/or `map_generator` (if you used the old style instantiation). Nevertheless, I'm going to check VGA timmings, as I can see a strange vertical line at the left of the screen, as if the hblank interval was visible.

By the way: I've changed the way you generate the display. You use regs for HS, VS, etc, which get updated the next clock cycle. I treat display generation as a FSM, so outputs come from combinational blocks triggered by certain values (or range of values) from the counters. Besides, I start horizontal and vertical counters so position (0,0) measured in pixel coordinates in the screen actually maps to values (0,0) from horizontal and vertical counters, so no arithmetic needed.

This is my version of VGA display generation:

```
module videosyncs (
   input wire clk,

   input wire [2:0] rin,
   input wire [2:0] gin,
   input wire [1:0] bin,

   output reg [2:0] rout,
   output reg [2:0] gout,
   output reg [1:0] bout,

   output reg hs,
   output reg vs,

   output wire [10:0] hc,
   output wire [10:0] vc
   );

   /* http://www.abramovbenjamin.net/calc.html */

   // VGA 640x480@60Hz,25MHz
   parameter htotal = 800;
   parameter vtotal = 524;
   parameter hactive = 640;
   parameter vactive = 480;
   parameter hfrontporch = 16;
   parameter hsyncpulse = 96;
   parameter vfrontporch = 11;
   parameter vsyncpulse = 2;
   parameter hsyncpolarity = 0;
   parameter vsyncpolarity = 0;

   reg [10:0] hcont = 0;
   reg [10:0] vcont = 0;
   reg active_area;

    assign hc = hcont;
    assign vc = vcont;

   always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (hcont == htotal-1) begin
         hcont <= 0;
         if (vcont == vtotal-1) begin
            vcont <= 0;
         end
         else begin
            vcont <= vcont + 1;
         end
      end
      else begin
         hcont <= hcont + 1;
      end
   end

   always @* begin
      if (hcont>=0 && hcont<hactive && vcont>=0 && vcont<vactive)
         active_area = 1'b1;
      else
         active_area = 1'b0;
      if (hcont>=(hactive+hfrontporch) && hcont<(hactive+hfrontporch+hsyncpulse))
         hs = hsyncpolarity;
      else
         hs = ~hsyncpolarity;
      if (vcont>=(vactive+vfrontporch) && vcont<(vactive+vfrontporch+vsyncpulse))
         vs = vsyncpolarity;
      else
         vs = ~vsyncpolarity;
    end

   always @* begin
      if (active_area) begin
         gout = gin;
         rout = rin;
         bout = bin;
      end
      else begin
         gout = 3'h00;
         rout = 3'h00;
         bout = 2'h00;
      end
   end
endmodule
```

Which is instantiated by your `vga_driver` module, which becomes nothing but a wrapper for this module:

```
module vga_driver (
  input wire clk_25MHz,
  output wire vs_vga,
  output wire hs_vga,
  output wire [2:0] RED,
  output wire [2:0] GREEN,
  output wire [1:0] BLUE,
  output wire HBLANK,
  output wire VBLANK,
  output [9:0] CURX,
  output [8:0] CURY,
  input [7:0] COLOR,
  input wire RESET
  );

  assign HBLANK = 0;
  assign VBLANK = 0;

  videosyncs syncgen (
     .clk(clk_25MHz),
     .rin(COLOR[7:5]),
     .gin(COLOR[4:2]),
     .bin(COLOR[1:0]),

     .rout(RED),
     .gout(GREEN),
     .bout(BLUE),

     .hs(hs_vga),
     .vs(vs_vga),

     .hc(CURX),
     .vc(CURY)
   );
endmodule
```

Note that in `map_generator`, the first `if` statement in this `always` block will never be true. We can forget about it, as the VGA display module will blank RGB outputs when needed.

```
  always @(posedge clk_vga) begin
    if(HBlank || VBlank) begin //
      mColor <= 0;             // Never reached
    end                        //
    else begin                 //
      if(currentMap == 4'b0000) begin
        mColor[7:0] <= startCastle[7:0];
      end
      //Add more maps later
    end
  end
```

---

Using the same approach, I've converted the map generator module to be a combinational module. For example, for map 0 (the castle -without the castle, I see-) it is like this:

```
module StartCastle(
  input wire [9:0] CurrentX,
  input wire [8:0] CurrentY,
  output wire [7:0] mapData
  );

  reg [7:0] mColor;
  assign mapData = mColor;

  always @* begin
    if(CurrentY < 40) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end
    else if(CurrentX < 40) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end
    else if(~(CurrentX < 600)) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end
    else if((~(CurrentY < 440) && (CurrentX < 260)) || (~(CurrentY < 440) && ~(CurrentX < 380))) begin
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b11100000;
    end else
      mColor[7:0] <= 8'b00011100;       
  end
endmodule
```

Just a FSM whose output is the colour that goes in a pixel. The input being the coordinates of the current pixel.

So when it is time to display map 0, map_generator simply switches to it based upon the current value of currentMap

```
module map_generator (
  input wire clk,
  input wire reset,
  input wire [9:0]CurrentX,
  input wire [8:0]CurrentY,
  input wire HBlank,
  input wire VBlank,
  input wire [9:0]playerPosX,
  input wire [8:0]playerPosY,
  output wire [7:0]mapData
  );

  reg [7:0] mColor;
  assign mapData = mColor;

  reg [5:0]currentMap = 0;

  wire [7:0] castle_map;
  StartCastle StartCastle(
    .CurrentX(CurrentX),
    .CurrentY(CurrentY),
    .mapData(castle_map)
  );

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(reset) begin
      currentMap <= 0;
    end
  end

  always @* begin
    if(currentMap == 6'b000000) begin
      mColor = castle_map;
    end
      //Add more maps later
  end
endmodule
```

This may look like a lot of comb logic is generated and so glitches may happen. It's actually very fast, no noticeable glitches on screen, and you can use the actual current x and y coordinates to choose what to display on screen. Thus, no need for an inverted clock. My final version of your design has only one 25MHz clock.

By the way, you want to keep device dependent constructions away from your design, placing things like clock generators in separate modules that will be connected to your design in the top module, which should be the only device dependent module.

So, I've written a device-agnostic adventure module, which will contain the entire game:

```
module adventure (
  input clk_vga,
  input reset,
  output vs_vga,
  output hs_vga,
  output [2:0] RED,
  output [2:0] GREEN,
  output [1:0] BLUE
  );

  wire HBLANK, VBLANK;
  wire [7:0] COLOR;
  wire [9:0] CURX;
  wire [8:0] CURY;
  wire [9:0] playerPosX = 10'd320;  // no actually used in the design yet
  wire [8:0] playerPosY = 9'd240;   // no actually used in the design yet

  vga_driver the_screen (.clk_25MHz(clk_vga), 
                         .vs_vga(vs_vga), 
                         .hs_vga(hs_vga), 
                         .RED(RED), 
                         .GREEN(GREEN), 
                         .BLUE(BLUE), 
                         .HBLANK(HBLANK), 
                         .VBLANK(VBLANK), 
                         .CURX(CURX), 
                         .CURY(CURY), 
                         .COLOR(COLOR)
                         );
  map_generator the_mapper (.clk(clk_vga), 
                            .reset(reset), 
                            .CurrentX(CURX), 
                            .CurrentY(CURY), 
                            .HBlank(HBLANK), 
                            .VBlank(VBLANK), 
                            .playerPosX(playerPosX), 
                            .playerPosY(playerPosY), 
                            .mapData(COLOR)
                            );
endmodule
```

This module is not complete: it lacks inputs from joystick or any other input device to update player current position. For now, player current position is fixed.

The top level design (TLD) is written exclusively for the FPGA trainer you have. It is here where you need to generate proper clocks using your device's available resources, such as the DCM in Spartan 3/3E devices.

```
module tld_basys(
  input wire clk_50MHz,
  input wire RESET,
  output wire vs_vga,
  output wire hs_vga,
  output wire [2:0] RED,
  output wire [2:0] GREEN,
  output wire [1:0] BLUE
  );

  wire clk_25MHz;  

  dcm_clocks gen_vga_clock (
                            .CLKIN_IN(clk_50MHz), 
                            .CLKDV_OUT(clk_25MHz)
                           );

  adventure the_game (.clk_vga(clk_25MHz), 
                      .reset(RESET), 
                      .vs_vga(vs_vga), 
                      .hs_vga(hs_vga), 
                      .RED(RED), 
                      .GREEN(GREEN), 
                      .BLUE(BLUE)
                      );
endmodule
```

The DCM generated clocks goes in this module (generated by the Xilinx Core Generator)

```
module dcm_clocks (CLKIN_IN, 
             CLKDV_OUT
             );

   input CLKIN_IN;
   output CLKDV_OUT;

   wire CLKFB_IN;
   wire CLKFX_BUF;
   wire CLKDV_BUF;
   wire CLKIN_IBUFG;
   wire CLK0_BUF;
   wire GND_BIT;

   assign GND_BIT = 0;
   BUFG  CLKDV_BUFG_INST (.I(CLKDV_BUF), 
                         .O(CLKDV_OUT));                         
   IBUFG  CLKIN_IBUFG_INST (.I(CLKIN_IN), 
                           .O(CLKIN_IBUFG));
   BUFG  CLK0_BUFG_INST (.I(CLK0_BUF), 
                        .O(CLKFB_IN));
   DCM_SP #(.CLKDV_DIVIDE(2.0), .CLKIN_DIVIDE_BY_2("FALSE"), 
         .CLKIN_PERIOD(20.000), .CLKOUT_PHASE_SHIFT("NONE"), 
         .DESKEW_ADJUST("SYSTEM_SYNCHRONOUS"), .DFS_FREQUENCY_MODE("LOW"), 
         .DLL_FREQUENCY_MODE("LOW"), .DUTY_CYCLE_CORRECTION("TRUE"), 
         .FACTORY_JF(16'hC080), .PHASE_SHIFT(0), .STARTUP_WAIT("FALSE") ) 
         DCM_SP_INST (.CLKFB(CLKFB_IN), 
                       .CLKIN(CLKIN_IBUFG), 
                       .DSSEN(GND_BIT), 
                       .PSCLK(GND_BIT), 
                       .PSEN(GND_BIT), 
                       .PSINCDEC(GND_BIT), 
                       .RST(GND_BIT), 
                       .CLKDV(CLKDV_BUF), 
                       .CLKFX(), 
                       .CLKFX180(), 
                       .CLK0(CLK0_BUF), 
                       .CLK2X(), 
                       .CLK2X180(), 
                       .CLK90(), 
                       .CLK180(), 
                       .CLK270(), 
                       .LOCKED(), 
                       .PSDONE(), 
                       .STATUS());
endmodule
```

Although it is safe (for Xilinx devices) to use a simple clock divider as you did. If you fear that the synthesizer won't treat your divided clock as an actual clock, add a BUFG primitive to route the output from the divider to a global buffer so it can be used as a clock with no problems (see the module above for an example on how to do this).

As a final note, you may want to add more independency from the final device, by using 24-bit colours for your graphics. At the TLD, you will use the actual number of bits per colour component you really have, but if you move from the Basys2 with 8-bit colour trainer board to the, say, Nexys4 board, with 12-bit colour, you will automatically enjoy a richer output display.

Now, it looks like this (no vertical bars at the left, and colours seem to be more vibrant)

[image: Another output from Basys using a different VGA display module]

Comment: I tried your videosyncs module and it seemed to fix the issue for the most part. I took care of the player movement in the top module. All dynamic objects are drawn in the top module where as all static objects are drawn by the map generator. 

I'm still relatively new to verilog and I'm actually doing this for my final project in my digital logic class, so this may seem like a remedial question but: What's the difference between @* and @(posedge clk)?

Comment: `@*` is used to define a block in which combinational logic is described using behavioural statements. `@(posedge clk)` is used to define a block in which sequential logic is described, again using behavioural statements. `@*` is the short form of `@(*)`, which in turn is the short form of `@(.... sensitivity list...... )`